# Slide Toggles and getting them to start closed

Tags: jquery, css

I have some collapsible elements on my page that I require closed upon launch. The thing is in order for them to open upon SlideToggle() they have to have a height making them visible.

So far I am using javascript on document load to slide them up as the page loads. surely there must be a better way using CSS?

Comment: can you provide some code... ?

Comment: Need to see your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a css property `display: none` to that collapsible element.